# Trouble with installing Monitorix (Centos 7)

Tags: perl, rpm, centos7, yum

I am trying to install Monitorix; but I can't seem to overcome certain issues with the required modules.

I have every prerequisite except for three of the perl modules (MIME-Lite, HTTP-Server-Simple, and Config-General). Even though I have installed them using CPAN, I can't seem to use rpm or yum to finish the installation process (I have the monitorix-3.9.0-1.noarch.rpm file downloaded).

Is there something I'm missing, or some way that is much easier to go about this? I started with a bare-bones Centos 7 system, in accordance to the nature of the course I have to do this for. Anything would be helpful, at this point.

Comment: It would be useful to see what errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing with CPAN is *not* the equivalent of installing them with `yum`; the installs are not in the RPM Database. Uninstall them and try again with `yum`, e.g. `yum install perl-MIME-Lite`.

Comment: The reason I tried CPAN was because trying yum gave me this error: "No package perl-MIME-Lite available". Could there be some intermediary step I'm missing, or perhaps there's something wrong with the RPM Database?

Comment: Try adding the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository to `yum`. Instructions are on that page.

Comment: I just discussed this with someone else, and they mentioned trying to do direct downloads from the epel repository...and it worked! Thanks you for the help.

Comment: Yes, you can directly download, but that defeats the purpose of a repository, which is the automatic dependency downloading as well.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll have to give that a shot next time (though I think it's good to have experience with direct downloads in case you can't implement the repository approach).